# Hide Custom Grid Mass Action for non administrator user

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, massaction, custom-grid

Currently I am working in Magento version-2.2.3. I have prepared one custom grid page using ui-component and added mass action on it which will be useful for admin. But now I want to hide Mass action option from users other then **administrator role**.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I have searched a lot and after some R&D I found the solution by my own. Posting so that it will be helpful to others also.

In your UI component, add **class** on your massaction element shown as below:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" class="NameSpace\MyModule\Ui\MassAction">
```

In this class, we will write our logic to hide/show our MassAction dropdown.

Below is my MassAction.php file which I created under **NameSpace/MyModule/UI/MassAction.php**

```
namespace NameSpace\MyModule\Ui;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as AuthSession;

class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        AuthSession $authSession,
        $components,
        array $data
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();

        $adminuser = $this->authSession->getUser();
        if ($adminuser) {
            $roleData = $adminuser->getRole()->getData();
            if (!(strtolower($roleData['role_name']) == strtolower(\NameSpace\MyModule\Block\Menu::ADMINSTRATORS))) {
                $this->setData('config', '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```